# Merge specific values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm currently merging the first and last `string` in a `row`. These `strings` are merged when they are to the right of a specific value. I'm hoping to change that to below a specific value.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'A' : ['X','Foo','','X','Big'],           
    'B' : ['No','','','No',''],
    'C' : ['Merge','Bar','','Merge','Cat'],
    })

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

m = df.A == 'X'

def f(x):
    s = x[x!= '']
    x[s.index[1]] = x[s.index[1]] + ' ' + x[s.index[-1]]
    x[s.index[-1]] = ''
    return x

df = df.astype(str).mask(m, df[m].apply(f, axis=1))
```

This code merges the first and last `string` when followed by `X`.

Output:

```
     A         B    C
0    X  No Merge     
1  Foo            Bar
2                    
3    X  No Merge     
4  Big            Cat
```

I'm hoping to change it to `rows` beneath the value `X`.

Intended Output:

```
         A   B      C
0        X  No  Merge
1  Foo Bar           
2                    
3        X  No  Merge
4  Big Cat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very similar, only boolean mask is shifted and first NaN is replaced to `False` and also indices from `[1]` are changed to `[0]` for seelct first value (of column `A`):

```
m = (df.A == 'X').shift().fillna(False)

def f(x):
    s = x[x!= '']
    x[s.index[0]] = x[s.index[0]] + ' ' + x[s.index[-1]]
    x[s.index[-1]] = ''
    return x

df = df.astype(str).mask(m, df[m].apply(f, axis=1))
print (df)
         A   B      C
0        X  No  Merge
1  Foo Bar           
2                    
3        X  No  Merge
4  Big Cat
```